# How do I call a custom function from within another custom cloud function within my index.ts file?

Tags: typescript, promise, google-cloud-functions

The overall goal here is to get a feel for how Firebase will be billing me for function invocations. I've defined a dummy function called `newUserFlow`  and a function called `addFriend`. If I call `newUserFlow` within `addFriend`, I want to see if the Firebase Console -> Cloud Functions -> Usage tab will show this as 1 function invoked or 2 functions invoked. However, I keep getting an error.

```
exports.newUserFlow = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return 'finished new user flow';
});

exports.addFriend = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('addFriend: ');
  const promise = exports.newUserFlow(null, null)
  // var outputVal: string;
  promise.then(async (outputVal: string) => { 
    console.log('addFriend_outputVal: ', outputVal)
    const uid1 = context?.auth?.uid; //current user 
    if (uid1) {
      var uid2: string;
      const docUID2 =  await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', data.targetUser).get();
      const friendsColl = 'friends_' + uid1
      if (!docUID2.empty) {
        docUID2.forEach(doc => {
          uid2 = doc.get('uid').toString(); //target UID
          if (uid2) {
            const docRef = admin.firestore().collection(friendsColl).doc();
            return docRef.set({
              friendUID: uid2,
              stat: 0, //0 = blocked, 1 = accepted, 2 = pending, 3 = declined 
              createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            })
          }
          else {
            return console.log('addFriend_Error: Target uid is empty.');
          }
        })
      }
      else {      
        return console.log('addFriend_Error: Target user not found.');
      }
    }
    else {
      return console.log('Error: user is not authorized');
    }
  }
    
  )

  promise.catch((outputVal: string) => {
    return console.log('addFriend_promisecatch')
  })
  
});
```

> error    Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't confuse a Cloud Function invocation with a JavaScript (or TypeScript) function invocation.  You can call as many JS functions as you want as part of a single Cloud Function invocation.  They don't cost extra per call.  You are only paying for the total extra amount of time it takes to call the function.

Secondly, it typically doesn't make sense for one callable type Cloud Function to invoke a second callable Cloud Function.  If you want two Cloud Functions to share some functionality, they should instead be calling a shared JS function.

```
exports.cloudFunction1 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    sharedJsFunction()
});
exports.cloudFunction2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    sharedJsFunction()
});

function sharedJsFunction() {
}
```

The error message about not returning a promise is completely unrelated to all of the above.  You will need to learn about how to handle promises correctly, and make sure your code returns a promise from the top level Cloud Function that resolves with the object to send back to the client.  Right now, your `addFriend` doesn't return anything at all.  Its returns statements are only returning from the anonymous callback function `async (outputVal: string) => {}`, not the main function.